# SQL Server - How to check all columns in table and exclude rows if rows have specific combination values

Tags: sql-server

Below is the sample data. I need to exclude rows  that have 'Yes' and 'N/A'.

result should exclude D and F records.

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | NO | Yes | N/A | N/A |
| B | NO | NO | NO | NO |
| C | NO | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| D | Yes | Yes | N/A | N/A |
| E | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| F | Yes | N/A | N/A | N/A |

Final OutPut:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | NO | Yes | N/A | N/A |
| B | NO | NO | NO | NO |
| C | NO | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| E | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You have rows with `Yes` and `N/A` in the result. Maybe you should edit the question and specify you want to exclude rows with "...only `Yes` and `N/A` values in columns..." or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want rows that have at least one `'NO'`, assuming these are the only three values:

```
where 'NO' in (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
```